# Which would be a better way to load data via ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax, theory

I am using google maps and returning html/lat/long from my MySQL database

### Currently

1. A user picks a business category e.g; "Video Production".
2. an ajax call is sent to a CodeIgniter controller
3. the Controller then queries the db, and returns the following data via JSON

   1. Lat/Long of the marker
   2. HTML for the popup window
   3. this is approximately 34 rows in the database across two tables per business
4. the ajax call receives this data and then plots the marker along with the html onto the map

The data that is returned from the controller is one big json object... This is done for all businesses that exist in the Video Production category (currently approx 40 businesses). As you can see, pulling this data for multiple categories (100s of businesses) can get very very taxing on the server.

### My question is

Would it be more beneficial to modify the process flow as such:

1. a user picks a business category e.g; "Video Production".
2. an ajax call is sent to a CodeIgniter controller
3. the controller then queries the database for the location base information

   1. lat/long
   2. level (used to change marker icon color)
   3. This would be a single row per business with several columns
4. the ajax call receives this data and then plots the marker on the map
5. when the user clicks a marker an ajax call is sent to a CodeIgniter Controller
6. the controller queries the database for the HTML and additional data based on business_id

and if not, what are some better suggestions to this problem?

**In summary this means rather than including the HTML and additional data along for each business, only submitting minimal location information and then re-query for that information when each business marker is clicked.**

### Potential Downsides

1. longer load times when a user clicks a marker icon
2. more code??
3. more queries to the database

Comment: I would say it really depends on how often you need multiple data points ... If you will frequently have multiple round-trip ajax calls it makes sense to load it all once. Also, unless you're talking about a sizable amount of data being returned from the Ajax call, you might as well go ahead and send it all at once.

Comment: one business has 36 rows of data returned, most categories are on average 60-100 businesses. The ability to select multiple categories is in the future road map. Which is why im asking this queston. As you can tell, `36*60` isn't a lot.. but when selecting 20 categories... it can definitely expand quickly

Comment: it should go to note, I will be using memcached to cache these query calls ... that too is in the roadmap :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you notice that this is causing some sort of performance issue, I would **leave as is**.

Generally, network round trips are the slowest item, and should be minimized as much as possible.  I would only worry about such an optimization once you get to the point where there is an observable performance issue.  Without profiling, it is impossible to tell which method will be truly faster, and it could be different for each user.  JSON is a fairly terse format,  and a lot of stuff can be condensed.

Also, if you do find that performance is an issue, you might want to look into client side templating (such as [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com), jQuery templates, Handlebars, Mustache, ...) for the popup window, assuming that the content is based off of a template.  This may allow you to minimize the data sent.

Comment: indeed a cached client side version of the popup is ideal.. and definitely another item we'll look into. Thanks for the comments

Comment: could you provide some example solutions for the client side templating? Would this be a good use for handlebars or mustache? To further complicate things, the popup layout is different for each level. Levels 1-4

Comment: Just edited.  I have never used handlebars or mustache, but that is the idea.  I use KnockoutJS mostly for this type of situation due to its two-way data binding, but any template engine would probably work, depending on your specific requirements.